# Merge two dataframes filling gaps

Tags: r

It does not seem to be a similar question here.

I would like to merge two dataframes to reach this structure:
[image]

My data looks like this:

```
m1 <- structure(list(Pays = c("BF", "BN    ", "CI    ", "ML    ", "NG    ", 
"SN    ", "TG    ", "UEMOA    ", "FR    ", "EA    "), BF = c(NA, 
"0.54    ", "0.50    ", "0.77*** ", "0.65    ", "0.92*** ", "0.73**  ", 
"0.81*** ", "0.58    ", "0.46    "), BN = c(NA, NA, "0.42    ", 
"0.38    ", "0.50    ", "0.62    ", "0.73*** ", "0.35    ", "0.50    ", 
"0.46    "), CI = c(NA, NA, NA, "0.73**  ", "0.62    ", "0.42    ", 
"0.38    ", "0.69*   ", "0.46    ", "0.50    "), ML = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "0.88*** ", "0.69*** ", "0.50    ", "0.96*** ", "0.65**  ", 
"0.62    "), NG = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.58    ", "0.62    ", 
"0.85*** ", "0.77*** ", "0.73**  "), SN = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "0.81*** ", "0.73*** ", "0.65    ", "0.54    "), TG = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.54    ", "0.69    ", "0.58    "), 
    UEMOA = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.69**  ", "0.65*   "
    ), FR = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.88*** "), 
    EA = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

m2 <- structure(list(Pays = c("BF", "BN", "CI", "ML", "NG", "SN", "TG", 
"UEMOA", "FR", "EA"), BF = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), BN = c("0.54    ", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), CI = c("0.50    ", "0.42    ", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ML = c("0.77*** ", "0.38    ", "0.73**  ", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), NG = c("0.65    ", "0.50    ", "0.62    ", 
"0.88*** ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), SN = c("0.92*** ", "0.62    ", 
"0.42    ", "0.69*** ", "0.58    ", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), TG = c("0.73**  ", 
"0.73*** ", "0.38    ", "0.50    ", "0.62    ", "0.81*** ", NA, 
NA, NA, NA), UEMOA = c("0.81*** ", "0.35    ", "0.69*   ", "0.96*** ", 
"0.85*** ", "0.73*** ", "0.54    ", NA, NA, NA), FR = c("0.58    ", 
"0.50    ", "0.46    ", "0.65**  ", "0.77*** ", "0.65    ", "0.69    ", 
"0.69**  ", NA, NA), EA = c("0.46    ", "0.46    ", "0.50    ", 
"0.62    ", "0.73**  ", "0.54    ", "0.58    ", "0.65*   ", "0.88*** ", 
NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `coalesce` to replace the NA element with the corresponding non-NA element from the different dataset column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
m1[-1] <- map2_dfc(m1[-1], m2[-1], coalesce)
```

-output

```
m1
#        Pays       BF       BN       CI       ML       NG       SN       TG    UEMOA       FR       EA
#1         BF     <NA> 0.54     0.50     0.77***  0.65     0.92***  0.73**   0.81***  0.58     0.46    
#2     BN     0.54         <NA> 0.42     0.38     0.50     0.62     0.73***  0.35     0.50     0.46    
#3     CI     0.50     0.42         <NA> 0.73**   0.62     0.42     0.38     0.69*    0.46     0.50    
#4     ML     0.77***  0.38     0.73**       <NA> 0.88***  0.69***  0.50     0.96***  0.65**   0.62    
#5     NG     0.65     0.50     0.62     0.88***      <NA> 0.58     0.62     0.85***  0.77***  0.73**  
#6     SN     0.92***  0.62     0.42     0.69***  0.58         <NA> 0.81***  0.73***  0.65     0.54    
#7     TG     0.73**   0.73***  0.38     0.50     0.62     0.81***      <NA> 0.54     0.69     0.58    
#8  UEMOA     0.81***  0.35     0.69*    0.96***  0.85***  0.73***  0.54         <NA> 0.69**   0.65*   
#9     FR     0.58     0.50     0.46     0.65**   0.77***  0.65     0.69     0.69**       <NA> 0.88*** 
#10    EA     0.46     0.46     0.50     0.62     0.73**   0.54     0.58     0.65*    0.88***      <NA>
```